# How to implement SAML V2 as SP (Want assertionsSigned=true and need sign cert)

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, rhel7

It is my fist time using SAML, and I'm tring to implement the SP side of it.
I have a working version of it in a dev environment, but the IDP in production require that my metadata have WantAssertionsSigned = true and to add a auto-signed certificate.
I've been tring to test this without success, can anyone here help me ?

I'm using RHEL 7 by the way.

From what i've understood, I need to generate a certificate, and to put it on a tomcat, but I do not use tomcat ...

Thanks for your help